Definition of a length function
I'm studying computability theory (only starting) using van den Dries's notes. On p. $6$, he defines $(\; )_2^2$ as
$(x)_2^2=\mu i_{\leq x}(\exists y \leq x|y, i|=x)$
and $\langle \; \rangle^d$ as:
$\langle x, y\rangle^2=|x, y|$, where
$(x, y) \mapsto|x, y|: \mathbb{N}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ is given by:
$$
|x, y|=\frac{(x+y)(x+y+1)}{2}+y . \tag{$\star$}
$$
and then extended to all $d \in \mathbb N.$ If I understand correctly it is Cantor's pairing function.
But then, on p. $7$ he defines $\text{lh} : \mathbb N \rightarrow \mathbb N$ by $\text{lh}(n) = (n)_2^2,$ "so that $\text{lh}(\langle n_1, \ldots , n_d \rangle) = d$."
Yet, when I tried to understand it by using an example, I'm getting something contradictory. Take $3=\langle 2, 0 \rangle.$ Then, $\text{lh}(3)=(3)_2^2=0,$ whereas I should naturally get $2$ as the output.
What am I missing/doing wrong? I would really appreciate any help, since a good part of the book relies on that coding/decoding, and I don't think I understand it well.

Your example is wrong: by definition, we have $\langle 2, 0 \rangle = \langle 2, 0, 2 \rangle^3 = | 3, 2 | = 17$, and $(17)_2^2 = 2$ as expected.
Note the definition of variable-length sequences, page 7: $\langle m_1, \dots, m_d \rangle$ is defined as $\langle m_1, \dots, m_d, d \rangle^{d+1}$. $\mathrm{lh}$ applies to variable-length sequences like $\langle 2, 0 \rangle$, not fixed-length sequences like $\langle 2, 0 \rangle^2$.

sorry, but I don't think I understand your answer: 1) why is $\langle 2, 0 \rangle = \langle 2, 0, 2 \rangle^3,$ and more importantly—why do we need to go from $2$-tuple to $3$-tuple to apply $\text{lh}$? 2) at the bottom of p. $5,$ he gives an explicit enumeration of $\mathbb N^2,$ where $(2,0) \mapsto 3.$ Also $\langle ; \rangle^2=|,, |$ and by plugging in $x=2, y=0$ into $\star$ we indeed get $3.$ What am I missing to get $17$ from that input? 3) Why couldn't we apply $()_2^2$ to $\langle2, 0\rangle$ and by def. of $()_2^2$ get the $2$nd element of the $2-$tuple as the output ie. $0$?


By definition, page 7. $\mathrm{lh}$ applies to variable-length sequences and extracts their length. 2) $|2, 0| = 3$ but $||2, 0|, 2| = 17$.


ah ok! I've missed that extending part, thanks for pointing that out. So basically what $\mathrm{lh}$ does behind the scenes in the most basic case is $\mathbb N \ni n \mapsto \langle :, \rangle^2 \mapsto \langle :, :, 2 \rangle^3 \mapsto \langle \langle , , , \rangle^2 , , 2 \rangle^2 \mapsto ()_2^2,$ correct? I understand this could also happen for any other $d$s than $2$ and $3,$ but I'm just trying to get the most basic idea right.

where the second $"\mapsto"$ mapping happens by the definition of variable-length sequences on p. $7$ you referenced

Your chain of $\mapsto$ doesn't make sense. $\mathrm{lh}$ is $()^2_2$, there's nothing behind the scenes. $\mathrm{lh}(\langle a, b \rangle) = \mathrm{lh}(\langle a, b, 2 \rangle^3) = (\langle a, b, 2 \rangle^3)^2_2 = (\langle \langle a, b \rangle^2, 2 \rangle^2)^2_2 = 2$.

I mean what you wrote is exactly what I meant (except that there is also the step where $n$ is encoded as a $2-$tuple, since by def. $\mathrm{lh}$ is $\mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$, not  $\mathbb{N}^2 \to \mathbb{N}$, but that's understood), so I think I understand everything now. Thank you for your help
